Dongle (IXXAT & PEAK) : How to handle lost connection
I got an external device which is connected to my application with a dongle (IXXAT or Peak).
I have to remake a part that don't work effectively.
So, I search for some information about the behaviour for any connection lost between my device and my dongle.
I mean, for example, how can I handle connection lost with an IXXAT or a Peak ? (any function, or do I just use a timer between two CAN message to check if there are still in communication?)
I work with C# .NET
My last colleague work use a timer time out for IXXAT, and TPCANStatus.PCAN_ERROR_QRCVEMPTY for Peak.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
